# Monterey - repeated kernel panics : watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from dfrd in 180 seconds

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, crash, kernel-panic, monterey

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019) is experiencing repeated kernel panics with the message below:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff02856d6ec): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from dfrd in 180 seconds
service: dfrd, total successful checkins since load (290 seconds ago): 11, last successful checkin: 180 seconds ago
service: remoted, total successful checkins since load (290 seconds ago): 29, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: bridgeaudiod, total successful checkins since load (290 seconds ago): 30, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: logd, total successful checkins since load (290 seconds ago): 29, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P744
macOS version: 21D62
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0: Wed Jan  5 20:03:37 PST 2022; root:xnu-8019.80.24~19/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5C49B2CB-9833-3D8A-8E98-E628559A4D1E
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.81.3
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xd
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x405060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x89271614
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x00000000201f4000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff0271f8000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1abd4138c
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x626d2d51 0x000d6866
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x626d2e77 0x00089b70

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff06e1b8000 - 0xfffffff06e1c8000
Native    : 0xffffffe0005fc000 - 0xffffffe6005fc000
Readonly  : 0xffffffe0e6c60000 - 0xffffffe133924000
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb00b0c000 - 0xffffffeb04cc4000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb0230c000 - 0xffffffeb02590000
CORE 0: PC=0x00000001a16d319c, LR=0x00000001a16d17d8, FP=0x000000016fac5a50
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
Total cpu_usage: 13973766
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xffffffe3006e1be0 watchdogd 97 0
0xffffffe3012ec000 bridgeaudiod 37 0
0xffffffe3012de2d8 watchdogd 31 0
0xffffffe3012f8df0 nfcd_relay 31 482365
0xffffffe3006c8df0 kernel_task 0 1953555

Panicked task 0xffffffe3e6bd3768: 190 pages, 3 threads: pid 36: watchdogd
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe3006e1be0, backtrace: 0xffffffeb0f0430c0, tid: 876
          lr: 0xfffffff0279eb6bc  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043100
          lr: 0xfffffff0279eb44c  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043170
          lr: 0xfffffff027b27008  fp: 0xffffffeb0f0431f0
          lr: 0xfffffff027b261d0  fp: 0xffffffeb0f0432a0
          lr: 0xfffffff0280515fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0f0432b0
          lr: 0xfffffff0279eb160  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043640
          lr: 0xfffffff0279eb160  fp: 0xffffffeb0f0436a0
          lr: 0xfffffff028b4b488  fp: 0xffffffeb0f0436c0
          lr: 0xfffffff02856d6ec  fp: 0xffffffeb0f0436e0
          lr: 0xfffffff02856d0e0  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043700
          lr: 0xfffffff027fcd128  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043760
          lr: 0xfffffff02856c5fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043880
          lr: 0xfffffff027fd6f10  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043a20
          lr: 0xfffffff027aee308  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043b40
          lr: 0xfffffff0279f1734  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043bd0
          lr: 0xfffffff0279c6cdc  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043d00
          lr: 0xfffffff0279dde78  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043d90
          lr: 0xfffffff027b1b8e8  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043e60
          lr: 0xfffffff027b26598  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043f10
          lr: 0xfffffff0280515fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0f043f20
```

It usually occurs within 5 minutes after booting up. The mouse suddenly freezes for a few seconds, then the system shuts down. Restarting results in the same issue.
Other observations:

1. TouchBar not visible
2. No known damage
3. No damage detected in Apple Diagnostics and Disk Utility.
4. Same issue in safe mode.

Comment: This [post at Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251673897) may shed some light on this.

Comment: @IconDaemon None of the suggestions in the post worked.

Comment: Same model and same problem. Any new info you can please share? Is your battery showing "Service Recommended"? I'm suspecting this might be related.

Comment: Any luck on this since then? I am running into the same error

Answer (score 7):

I set up a cronjob for every 3 minutes to restart the TouchBar. Since I set up the cronjob, I did not have a single kernel panic.

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/pkill "Touch Bar agent" &>/dev/null; /usr/bin/killall "ControlStrip" &>/dev/null;
```

Use `crontab -e` in a Terminal to create the cronjob.

Comment: Thanks, on Sonoma the process is “TouchBarServer”, as @Edm noted below for Monterey.  Used `sudo crontab -e` to apply the command in one terminal while running `while true; do sleep 30; sudo pkill TouchBarServer; date; done` in another.

Answer (score 3):

Just to help you out, I had this issue yesterday.
With the exact same error.

The kernel panic is in relation to BootOS, the Mac software side that runs the Touch Bar.

If this has failed or disconnected then this is what causes the error.
Recovery will fail the same, and Apple Diagnostics shows no faults.

The good news is that the Touch Bar can be replaced and is a separate piece to the keyboard, hope this helps you or anyone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `watchdog` process, which makes sure that all systems are operating properly, has gone too long without communicating with `dfrd`, which controls the Touch Bar. If there's no communication for 3 minutes (180 seconds), `watchdog` assumes there's a catastrophic error and shuts down the entire system.

If there's a history of damage to the computer or Touch Bar, then a hardware fix might be necessary. In the absence of such history, there might be a workaround in software. I had no history of damage to the computer, no hardware check failures, and no issues while using my 2020 Intel MBP (except for a period of blinking of the light on the TouchBar when waking from sleep), but with a similar kernel panic due to lack of communication with `dfrd` turning off the computer during its sleep at night.

The answer from @pesc uses a "cronjob" to turn off the Touch Bar, which then restarts automatically, every 3 minutes. As that works, I assume that `dfrd` sends a message to `watchdog` each time the Touch Bar restarts so that the 3-minute window never is reached. If you're not comfortable with setting up a "cronjob" you can do the same with AppleScript.

In Monterey, the process to `pkill` is called `TouchBarServer`; killing it also restarts the `ControlStrip` process without having to do that separately. Choose the name of the process that is used in your OS version.

I used the following as guides to write an AppleScript that seems to be working in my case: a suggestion from Nitrokev2 at [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/the-dreaded-touchbar-flicker.2278391/page-2), and a similar [Mac O'Clock post](https://medium.com/macoclock/macbook-touchbar-flicker-fix-bafa754aae13).

As a protected system process, to `pkill` the `TouchBarServer` you need administrator privileges. The sources I found recommended this code to invoke `pkill`:

```
do shell script "pkill TouchBarServer" user name "YourUserNameGoesThere" password "YourPasswordGoesThere" with administrator privileges
```

To avoid putting my administrator password in plain text in the script, I used different code made possible by a single addition to `/etc/sudoers`, starting with the terminal command

```
% sudo visudo
```

That opens by default a `vi` editor of the file. With that ancient file editor, the meaning of a keystroke differs depending on the context, so I used a [cheat sheet](https://www.shell-tips.com/cheat-sheets/vim-quick-references/) to refresh my memories from decades ago. That method for editing allows a check that there are no errors in the new `sudoers` before saving the changes, as errors could be catastrophic. Don't try this on your own with a different text editor.

The `sudoers` file contained in part:

```
##
# User specification
##

# root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
root            ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin          ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

I added the following line immediately thereafter.

```
eam             ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pkill TouchBarServer
```

so that I will still be prompted for my password for other administrative commands. (`eam` is my user name; replace with your own.) When the change is saved, you should be able to use the terminal command

```
% sudo pkill TouchBarServer
```

and see the Touch Bar turn off and on without being prompted for a password. That allows me to keep my password out of the script.

The AppleScript app below is saved as a "stay-open" application in Applications and included in my startup items. For my situation, I restart `TouchBarServer` once a minute when the computer has been idle for a minute or more. (I fear that every 3 minutes might be cutting things too close.) For the problem described by the OP, one might adapt the script to just restart `TouchBarServer` every minute regardless of idle state.

```
global timeBeforeComputerIsNotInUse

on run
    set timeBeforeComputerIsNotInUse to 60 -- 1 minute
end run

on idle
    set idleTime to (do shell script "ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | awk '/HIDIdleTime/ {print $NF/1000000000; exit}'") as number
    
    if idleTime is greater than or equal to timeBeforeComputerIsNotInUse then
        do shell script "sudo pkill TouchBarServer"
    end if
    
    return 60 -- repeat the idle handler code every 60 seconds
end idle

on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

If you don't want the app icon to show up in the Dock, see the [Mac O"Clock post](https://medium.com/macoclock/macbook-touchbar-flicker-fix-bafa754aae13) for how to edit its `Info.plist` accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Same issues, same messages, with my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), latest IOS, battery condition: normal.
last 60 minutes 6 times panic reboot.

I changed:

- Battery and Power Adapter -> Turn display off after: -> Never.
- Power Adapter -> Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping when the display, is off enabled.
- Security & Privacy -> Developer Tools, removed Terminal

it seems a little better so far.