# Possible to make watchdog process ignore faults in the dynamic function row daemon (dfrd)?

Tags: kernel-panic, touch-bar

I have a 2020 Intel MacBook Pro with TouchBar. The TouchBar hardly functions; it sometimes flashes erratically, turns off, and will not turn on again until the computer restarts. When the TouchBar fails, the dynamic function row daemon (`dfrd`) causes then causes kernel panics in the `watchdog` process as described in [Monterey - repeated kernel panics : watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from dfrd in 180 seconds](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440480/monterey-repeated-kernel-panics-watchdog-timeout-no-successful-checkins-fro). Unfortunately, the solution from that post doesn't resolve the issue because attempting to restart the TouchBar from the terminal doesn't work.

I usually use my laptop in clamshell mode with an external keyboard so I don't miss the TouchBar at all. But if I ever open the laptop or unplug it from the monitors, it causes a kernel panic.

Would it be possible to make the watchdog process ignore the `no successful checkins from dfrd in 180 seconds` error? I'd be happy for any solution that doesn't require spending $600 for Apple to fix a useless (to me) piece of hardware.