MacBook restarting multiple times a day with "userspace watchdog timeout" error – how to resolve?
My MacBook has been restarting several times a day with the following panic error. I suspect it might be related to the logd service, but I’m not sure how to debug or fix it. Here’s the full error message:

panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff028adfdc4): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from logd (0 induced crashes) in 180 seconds
logd last exited with reason namespace: SIGNAL, code 5
service: dfrd, total successful checkins in 11961 seconds: 1195, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: remoted, total successful checkins in 11950 seconds: 1196, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: bridgeaudiod, total successful checkins in 11961 seconds: 1196, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: logd, total successful checkins in 11961 seconds: 1152, last successful checkin: 180 seconds ago

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 22P353
macOS version: 24A348
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 24.0.0: Mon Aug 12 20:39:22 PDT 2024; root:xnu-11215.1.10~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
KernelCache UUID: 0AD96D3C6D0EC892E1A31B6B972B8114
Kernel UUID: BFEE985D-CFDF-35F8-89BE-DD7CCFE3C770
Boot session UUID: FEFF0674-D8CC-411B-B1D2-9C27CFF6D0C9
iBoot version: iBoot-11881.1.1
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0xec
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x70707060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x1614
macOS kernel slide: 0x1c400000
Paniclog version: 14
Kernel slide:      0x0000000021ddc000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff028de0000
mach_absolute_time: 0x42d787b651
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x673b19c1 0x000554f2
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x673b4876 0x0004333a

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffdfa6eac000 - 0xffffffe5a6eac000
  . VM    : 0xffffffdfa6eac000 - 0xffffffe08d510000
  . RO    : 0xffffffe08d510000 - 0xffffffe0da1dc000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffe0da1dc000 - 0xffffffe1c0840000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffe1c0840000 - 0xffffffe2a6ea4000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffe2a6ea4000 - 0xffffffe38d50c000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffe38d50c000 - 0xffffffe473b74000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe473b74000 - 0xffffffe5a6eac000
  Metadata: 0xffffffe5a6f64000 - 0xffffffe5a8764000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffe5a8764000 - 0xffffffe5a887c000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xffffffe38d9bd018  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x000000016b6d70e0 }
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffff029124a04, LR=0xfffffff028fb46b8, FP=0xffffffee36847f20
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Total cpu_usage: 15134120
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xffffffe38d9bd018 watchdogd 97 0
0xffffffe38d9d0940 watchdogd 31 0
0xffffffe38d5d2b78 kernel_task 0 4809412
0xffffffe38d5ec940 kernel_task 0 5226741

Panicked task 0xffffffe1c0f8ea38: 151 pages, 4 threads: pid 38: watchdogd
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe38d9bd018, backtrace: 0xffffffee367e7110, tid: 949
          lr: 0xfffffff028fe9f70  fp: 0xffffffee367e7180
          lr: 0xfffffff029123010  fp: 0xffffffee367e71f0
          lr: 0xfffffff02912210c  fp: 0xffffffee367e72e0
          lr: 0xfffffff028fa96bc  fp: 0xffffffee367e72f0
          lr: 0xfffffff028fe99b0  fp: 0xffffffee367e76c0
          lr: 0xfffffff0296ce928  fp: 0xffffffee367e76e0
          lr: 0xfffffff028adfdc4  fp: 0xffffffee367e7700
          lr: 0xfffffff028adf444  fp: 0xffffffee367e7720
          lr: 0xfffffff028ade594  fp: 0xffffffee367e7840
          lr: 0xfffffff029645a98  fp: 0xffffffee367e7880
          lr: 0xfffffff029645e3c  fp: 0xffffffee367e7a20
          lr: 0xfffffff0290f0690  fp: 0xffffffee367e7b40
          lr: 0xfffffff028ff0404  fp: 0xffffffee367e7be0
          lr: 0xfffffff028fcb1ac  fp: 0xffffffee367e7c50
          lr: 0xfffffff028fdc0c4  fp: 0xffffffee367e7d70
          lr: 0xfffffff029117f64  fp: 0xffffffee367e7e20
          lr: 0xfffffff0291226e0  fp: 0xffffffee367e7f10
          lr: 0xfffffff028fa96bc  fp: 0xffffffee367e7f20




This may be a hardware issue involving the TouchBar. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440480/monterey-repeated-kernel-panics-watchdog-timeout-no-successful-checkins-fro

There are no any visible issues with TouchBar and it is working as expected.

Unless you have a good reason to be running macOS 15.0.1, I suggest you update to the latest version (15.1). That might get you a bug fix.

No any fixes related to the above issue. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-15_1-release-notes

The release notes don't mention every bug fix. Updating may not solve the problem, but I think it's a reasonable first step. However, if you prefer to put that off, then test in Safe Mode. It may be difficult to do that if the panics are not reproducible.
